# No package even after package installation alert

Tags: android, youtube, box, television

After viewing the YouTube app that came preinstalled in my Android TV Box (Android 7.1.2 OS) for about 6 hours without any problems, now when I launch the YouTube app I get "The installation package was not found." This happened by itself with me fiddling around with the settings. I would turn on the TV Box, launch the app, watch it for awhile, then turn off the box. The box is new and I have only used it 3 times since I got it. Any suggestions for solving this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question isn't about programming, and probably belongs to https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the link, as I'm the person who posted the question.